# Batch: copy content of one txt file into another

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

Hi this is what i want to do:

I define a directory e.g. `C:\TEXT`.
If a `txt` file is posted/generated/moved into that directory, it opens the `txt` file copies its content, generates a new `txt` file, pastes that content into the new file and deletes the old one, is that possible?

It is fine if both `txt` files have pre-defined names.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help here!

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and describe where you are stuck! and please provide an example, because it is not quite clear what you are asking; without any more details, it looks like you just want to move a file...

Comment: Since im not familiar with batch i havent tried much, what i want is to copy the contents of one txt file to a new one since my programm that generates the txt corrupts the codec of the file , thats why i junt want to have its content transfered

Comment: If you just want to copy the text, why not copy the file using the default [copy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx) command?

Comment: Because i need the txt file to be made anew and just the content copied, I dont see a function for that on the copy manual

Comment: @finua, I am not understanding why you think the COPY command will not work for this.

Comment: @Squashman for me it looks like copy just copies the whole file, not just its contents to a new file or am i mistaken there?

Comment: @finua could you please explain how you think copying the whole file is different then copying the contents?

Comment: @Squashman i managed to solve this problem thanks to leptonator but to your question:
MY original file has a corrupt codec or format, for an unknown reason ... thats why i want its contents copied what TYPE managed to do for me just fine, thanks for the time you invested and keeping up with me ^^

Comment: @finua, Your file is not corrupt! Your file is a UNICODE file which is why the TYPE command works when you output it to a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
TYPE 1.TXT > FINAL.TXT
TYPE 2.TXT >> FINAL.TXT
```

Note: the ">" will over-write.  The ">>" will append or add to a file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @echo off
  break>"c:\TEXT\example.txt"
  TYPE c:\TEXT\DHL-Export.txt >> c:\TEXT\example2.txt

dit it perfectly for me, thank you alot :D

Comment: NOTE: You should be able to do: `COPY 1.txt+2.txt FINAL.txt` ..  You may have to experiment a bit as well to get the desired results.. Ref - http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html

Comment: Minor issue..  Plese be CAREFUL: Use @ECHO OFF only when you are done debugging your Script..   Otherwise, you may not see the correct behaviors when you are trying to verify good operation in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The following will accomplish the same with Boxed headings for every text file or batch file depending on your choice. Simply change the *.txt to *.bat or any text based file and the output will have a boxed heading of the filename along with the actual text from inside.

```
 @echo off
 ::If the file "Allbatchfiles.txt exists in the running folder then delete it. 
 IF EXIST Allbatchfiles.txt (
    del Allbatchfiles.txt
)
 :: For every file with the ".bat" extention Make an entry with 
 :: a Boxed heading of the filename and the contents of the file
 :: and output to the file Allbatchfiles.txt

 for %%f in (*.bat) do echo. >>AllBatchfiles.txt && echo ============================================ >>AllBatchfiles.txt && echo ----------"%%f"---------- >> AllBatchfiles.txt && echo ============================================ >>AllBatchfiles.txt && type "%%f" >>AllBatchfiles.txt
```